# How do I install lcms in virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-imaging-library

I have been trying to install lcms in virtualenv but is failing so far. Any suggestions on how I should go about it?

My virtualenv is created like so:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 /path/to/venv
```

All I want is to get this to work (print "OK"):

```
python -c "import lcms;print 'OK'"
```

But now, whatever/however package I install, I always get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named lcms
```

Among other things I have tried several variants of [pillow-installations](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/installation.html), like this for example:

```
pip install pillow --global-option="build_ext" --global-option="--enable-lcms"
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Did you activate the virtual environment? (`. venv/bin/activate`)

Comment: Yes I did. When outside the `virtualenv` it actually works since i Installed the required `liblcms2-dev`. But once activated I do not get access to the global site-packages (this is the default behavior of virtualenv).